# How to get rid of duplicate entries in rEFInd?

Tags: arch-linux, refind

So I have installed rEFInd as a bootloader for my Linux installation (on a Virtual Box before trying on actual hardware).

I have configured the refind_linux.conf file as follows:

```
## This file should be present in the same directory as the EFISTUB kernel and initramfs files
## More info at http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/linux.html , http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/efistub.html

"Boot with defaults"    "root=PARTUUID=$partuuid rw add_efi_memmap"
"Boot to terminal"      "root=PARTUUID=$partuuid rw add_efi_memmap systemd.unit=multi-user.target"
```

Where $partuuid is replaced by the actual partuuid of the partition on which / is mounted.

I also created a menu entry in the refind.conf file in order to have the fancy Arch Linux icon and not a generic Linux one:

```
menuentry "Arch Linux" {
    icon     /EFI/refind/icons/os_arch.png
    loader   /vmlinuz-linux
    initrd   /initramfs-linux.img
    options  "ro root=PARTUUID=$partuuid"
    submenuentry "Boot using fallback initramfs" {
        initrd /initramfs-linux-fallback.img
    }
    submenuentry "Boot to terminal" {
        add_options "systemd.unit=multi-user.target"
    }
}
```

When I boot, I can see the rEFInd menu, but I have two entries:

[image]

[image]

Both start properly. I only have one linux kernel file in the /boot directory tree so this seems redundant.

How can I get rid of the generic menu entry and only keep the Arch one?

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to prevent rEFInd to scan for bootloaders automatically, and to only keep the manually defined entry menus.

In refind.conf, uncomment and modify the following line:

```
scanfor external,optical,manual
```

(I removed the internal scanning)